# Extending a line to the left of an element without overlapping the element

Tags: css

I am trying to create a solid line that extends both *to* and *from* the left side of an element. I can create one that extends *to* the left, but it overlaps the element (in this case an H2). I need it to "start" before the text does. I can use something like `right: 15px` to solve this problem, but I would need to adjust the px size in every instance this is used since some H2s will be longer, and some shorter. I would like to find a solution that doesn't require different `right` values since this will be used with multiple H2s of various lengths.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
h2::before {
display: inline-block;
content: "";
height: 3px;
background: #E47325;
position: absolute;
width: 400%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -2px;
}
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image: This is how it currently looks]

And this is how I would like it to look ideally, without having to arbitrarily set padding to the right side:

[image: And this is how I would like it to look ideally, without having to arbitrarily set padding to the right side]

Comment: If you want to show the solution you ended up using, please add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background: #E47325;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;               /* Added */
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(-100% - 10px); /* Added */
  margin-top: -2px;
}

 /* And the same on the other side */
h2::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background: #E47325;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(100% + 10px);  /* Different here */
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello</h2>
```

Comment: This basically got it exactly right. I had my width set to 400% for a reason (to ensure it extended to the left past another column. So I had to adjust your 'calc' from "left: calc(100% - 10px)" to "left: calc(400% - 10px)", and keep my "width: 400%," but this worked perfectly once I did that. Thanks so much! Been pulling my hair out for a few days on this haha.

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap `<h2>` in a `<header>` (or any block element but `<header>` is 100% semantic).
- Assign `::before` to `<header>` instead. Make `<header>` `position: relative`
- Assign `h2` `position: absolute` and `z-index: 1`
- Assign `header::before` `position: absolute` as well
- The `height` and `top` values are based on the browser default `font-size: 1.5em` of `h2` -- so adjust accordingly if `h2` `font-size` has been altered.

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 1.625em;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 1.3125em);
  width: max-content;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

header::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1.5px);
  height: 3px;
  width: 99%;
  background: #E47325;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
</header>
<header>
  <h2>A LONGER HEADING</h2>
</header>
```